# Meaning of !chkimg errors for a crash dump

Tags: windows, security, debugging, windbg, malware

I have a strange crash dump of my app for which I cannot figure out the crash reason. I noticed that the [!chkimg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562217(v=vs.85).aspx) command reveals some errors in the dump:

```
0:013> !chkimg
824985 errors : @eip (77230010-7731016b)
```

The address range 77230010-7731016b belongs to a ntdll.dll module.
Is it a definite sign of malware affected my program? Can I somehow confirm or eliminate this hypothesis?

EDIT:
Some additions based on the blabb's answer:

> the range size is 917851 out of which 824985 is altered in ntdll (by default !chkimg does not check writable sections so the output seesm suspicous

I executed the command in the latest version of windbg and it found 8219 not 824985 errors.

> you cannot assume a machine is malwared based on a possibly probably corrupt dump

My app consists of several different processes/executables and I have dumps almost for each of the them. And !chkimg returns the same errors for all of them.

> the dumpwrite path can have problems during a bsod and corrupt dump could be written

All the dumps are user mode not kernel.

Also I get the following warning while reloading the symbols:

*** WARNING: symbols timestamp is wrong 0x521ea8e7 0x4ce7ba58 for ntdll.dll

Comment: What kind of crash is it? Could it be that memory of the DLL was overwritten, e.g. by a buffer overflow?

Comment: Is it possible for buffer overflow to corrupt ntdll.dll image loaded in process memory? I believe such an attempt would fail with access violation.

Comment: You're right, of course the DLL pages should be PAGE_READONLY.

Comment: @ThomasW., Well, probably `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`. What soft of "crash" are we talking about here? And what does that thread's callstack look like?

Comment: DLLs are mapped as Copy-on-Write, which is a special case of read only. Attempts to write to the pages will succeed, though the modifications will not appear in other processes

Comment: @snoone, then why I get access violation for the code like `HANDLE h = GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"); *((int*)h) = 1;` ?

Comment: Probably the first page is marked PAGE_READONLY since there's no code to execute there. Just data from the PE header for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the range size is `917851` out of which `824985` is altered in ntdll (by default !chkimg does not check writable sections  so the output seesm suspicous

use `chkimg -d`  it should show you the places where the original file differs from the one that is memory
or force the command to scan the module ntdll with `chkimg -d ntdll`

you cannot assume a machine is malwared based on a possibly probably corrupt dump
the dumpwrite path can have problems during a bsod and corrupt dump could be written
check with chkimg -db which may show all zeroes in the areas where it is checking
i assume you have a kernel full dump

```
orginal file address xxxxxxxx 60 90 cc 
memory file                   00 00 00
```

the above can show such  huge discrepancy in chkimg output

```
lkd> !chkimg nt -d
    80501bc8-80501bcb  4 bytes - nt!KiServiceTable+24
    [ ec cb 60 80:a0 9a 3e a9 ]
    80501bf0-80501bf3  4 bytes - nt!KiServiceTable+4c (+0x28)
    [ 44 c9 5c 80:7e a5 3e a9 ]
    80501c08-80501c0b  4 bytes - nt!KiServiceTable+64 (+0x18)
    [ ba 1c 5b 80:5d e8 42 a9 ]
```

it is possible to overwrite only the section of binary that is marked  `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE` writing to any other section will generate an Access Violation 
and chkimg unless forced to does not compare these sections with  `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE` attributes in pe header so what ever is shown in your query are in places where no modifications are allowed or expected.

here is a sample code that takes a dll name and tries writing to .data section

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc,char *argv[]) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argc);
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary(argv[1]);
    if (hMod)   {
        PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER doshead = ( PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER ) hMod;
        DWORD ntoffset = doshead->e_lfanew + (DWORD)hMod;
        DWORD datsecoffset = ntoffset + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS);
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nthead = ( PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS )( ntoffset );
        DWORD totsections = nthead->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
        for (DWORD i = 0 ; i< totsections ; i++) {
            PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sechead = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER ) 
                (datsecoffset + i * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));
            if( ( sechead->Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE ) == 
                IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE ) {
                    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo; 
                    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
                    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(out, &csbiInfo);
                    WORD oldcolor = csbiInfo.wAttributes;
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(out,10);
                    printf(
                        "Module %p Section %s is writable trying to write\n",
                        hMod,sechead->Name);
                    for( DWORD j = sechead->VirtualAddress ; 
                        j < sechead->VirtualAddress + sechead->SizeOfRawData ; 
                        j++)  {
                            BYTE Inbyte = *(BYTE *) ( (BYTE *)hMod + j);
                            *(BYTE *) ( (BYTE *)hMod + j) = Inbyte;
                    }
                    printf(
                        "Module %p Section %s is written to successfully\n",
                        hMod,sechead->Name);
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(
                        GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),oldcolor);
            } else {
                printf(
                    "Module %p Section %s is not writable skipping\n",
                    hMod,sechead->Name);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

output on a hexedited dll and ntdll below

```
:\>xxd -s +0x3c -l 4 -g 4 sec_attr_mod_dll.dll
000003c: b0000000                             ....    
:\>set /a 0xb0 + 0xf8 + 0x24
460
:\>xxd -s +460 -l 4 -g 4 sec_attr_mod_dll.dll & xxd -s +500 -l 4 -g 4 sec_attr_m
od_dll.dll & xxd -s +540 -l 4 -g 4 sec_attr_mod_dll.dll & xxd -s +580 -l 4 -g 4
sec_attr_mod_dll.dll
00001cc: 400000c0                             @...
00001f4: 400000c0                             @...
000021c: 400000c0                             @...
0000244: 400000c2                             @...

:\>w2dl.exe sec_attr_mod_dll.dll
Module 10000000 Section .text is writable trying to write
Module 10000000 Section .text is written to successfully
Module 10000000 Section .rdata is writable trying to write
Module 10000000 Section .rdata is written to successfully
Module 10000000 Section .data is writable trying to write
Module 10000000 Section .data is written to successfully
Module 10000000 Section .reloc is writable trying to write
Module 10000000 Section .reloc is written to successfully

:\>w2dl.exe ntdll.dll
Module 7C900000 Section .text is not writable skipping
Module 7C900000 Section .data is writable trying to write
Module 7C900000 Section .data is written to successfully
Module 7C900000 Section .rsrc is not writable skipping
Module 7C900000 Section .reloc is not writable skipping

:\>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my question to add some info based on your suppositions.

Comment: if you have a symbol problem then you cannot expect !chkimg to work properly try .symfix+  look at your downstream symbol folder for ntdll.dll  and ntdll.pdb  save it somewhere just in case delete both the folders and grab a fresh set of symbols and dlls from microsoft symbol servers and then do a !chkimg from a short google it seems the dll details belong to w2k8 x64 syswow ensure you are using the correct bit of windbg Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7ba58
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18247, time stamp: 0x521ea8e7

Comment: Hmm, `lmDvmntdll` prints: `Timestamp: Thu Aug 29 05:50:31 2013 (521EA8E7)` and `FileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)`. Google says that 521EA8E7 corresponds to 6.1.7601.18247, not 6.1.7601.17514. Also I see it for my local c:\windows\syswow64\ntdll.dll. How is it possible?

Comment: i have read reports of mismatched dumps  happening when clr frameworks have been updated/patched and dump taken during that window may be the ntdll was updated when you took the dump just a wild guess  does the mapped memory image file contain the timestamp and size  ntdll.dll\49901D48b2000\ Timestamp:        Mon Feb 09 17:40:48 2009 (49901D48)
see if both coincides in your lmdvm  (mmapim file is one that was downloaded from symbol server ) else discard the sympath set new .sympath with  .sympath srv*c:\sym**http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols & grab a fresh set of syms in a new folder

Comment: I have three folders 515FAC6E157000, 521EA8E7180000, 523D45FA168000 inside ntdll.dll cache folder but not 49901D48b2000.
I reset sympath to a new folder and 521EA8E7180000\ntdll.dll was downloaded with version 6.1.7601.18247 and timestamp 521EA8E7.
Warning about mismatched timestamp and !chkimg errors are still as before.